# How to debug the problom? An elf file cannot be run, but the printing from the ldd and file seems no problem

Tags: debugging, elf

some command printing:

```bsh
$ ./omnetpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
zsh: no such file or directory: ./omnetpp

$ file ./omnetpp
./omnetpp: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b621fbc20e80d7ac375ece11a5775fc6686b71c7, with debug_info, not stripped

$ ldd omnetpp
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc8cd2b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /nix/store/pnd2kl27sag76h23wa5kl95a76n3k9i3-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f84d65ea000)
    libdl.so.2 => /nix/store/pnd2kl27sag76h23wa5kl95a76n3k9i3-glibc-2.27/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f84d65e5000)
    libc.so.6 => /nix/store/pnd2kl27sag76h23wa5kl95a76n3k9i3-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f84d642f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/pnd2kl27sag76h23wa5kl95a76n3k9i3-glibc-2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f84d660d000)

$ uname -a
Linux nixos 4.19.87 #1-NixOS SMP Sun Dec 1 08:17:47 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The above messages seems that I have all the necessary libaraies.

Further more, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/Vonfry/6f5b82ae0479a72b7eb1135f79ebbadf) for a full printing from `readelf -a`

If I try to run this elf file with lldb, it returns `error: process launch failed: 'A' packet returned an error: 8`.

Now, I want to know if there is a way to find what I miss.

EDIT:
A build script and process can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/Vonfry/omnetpp-nix/tree/64211c7f29b570001148947f2c5ecd77a27c8d63/).

Comment: This seems to be missing the most fundamental information: what error you get when you actually run it. The "process launch failed" error is from LLDB itself, so is not much help.

Comment: @ChrisDown I add an error message from shell, but I think it is also unuseful. `no such file or directory: ./omnetpp`

Comment: What are the permission flags on `omnetpp`? Any ACL, or SELinux policies? Is the file on a filesystem where execution is allowed?

Comment: @xenoid Of course, all these have been checked. ALC is not openned. and it has exeuction and read permission.

Comment: Is the filesystem mounted with the `noexec` directive?

Comment: @Lambert No. And other exec can be run on the same one.

Comment: It seems that there are lots of trailing characters on your first line of shell output. Are there any special characters in the filename resulting in `no such file or directory` when you call it that way?